# Unusual learning curve results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to machine learning and would appreciate any help. I am working on a supervised binary classification problem with a small dataset (110 samples) in which I have selected some models to try and performed hyperparameter tuning with cross-validated grid search. I then generated learning curves for each model with the code below:

```
from yellowbrick.model_selection import LearningCurve

final_models = [("KNN", knn_final), 
                ("SVMRBF", svm_final), 
                ("RandomForest", rf_final), 
                ("MLP", mlp_final)]

for name, model in final_models:
    y_train = np.ravel(y_train)
    kfold = model_selection.RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 10, random_state = 42)
    learning_curve = LearningCurve(model, cv = kfold, scoring = "roc_auc", 
                           train_sizes = np.linspace(0.3, 1.0, 10), n_jobs = -1)
    learning_curve.fit(X_train_trans, y_train)
    learning_curve.show()
```

This generated the learning curves below:

[KNN learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU5i2.png)

[SVC learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YUiQ.png)

[Random forest learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6d0D.png)

[MLP learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNLs2.png)

I am a bit confused by the learning curves that it generated. The one for SVC looks similar to examples I have seen with overfitting, but how is there a perfect training score for the other models? Are these curves valid and just demonstrative of severe overfitting, or did I do something wrong?

My other question is if the models are overfitting, why didn't grid search select values for the hyperparameters that allow the model to generalize better? For example, the MLP grid search selected a hidden layer size of 20 and alpha of 0. Based on the overfitting, it seems it would benefit from a smaller hidden layer size and larger alpha. These options were in the grid but not selected.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have an extreme overfitting problem. Is it possible that you forgot to drop the label in your training dataset(X_train) or something like that?